# How to use binary search to find a function

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, computer-science, roots, searching

I am reading somewhere that $$(\phi'(y))^{-1}=y^{-c_1}+y^{-c_2},$$ $c_1,c_2$ are some numbers, can be solved for $\phi$ using binary search. I am surprised because binary search binary search is used to find number in a list. What does this mean really?

Answer (score 1):

You usually use it to find a root of a function in some interval.  If you have a function $f$ that is continuous on $[a,b]$ with $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ of opposite signs, the intermediate value theorem guarantees that there is at least one root in the interval.  You evaluate $f(\frac12(a+b))$, replace the endppoint of the interval of the same sign, and keep going.  The interval gets cut in half at each step.  There are other, often faster, one dimensional [root finding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) techniques.  They are discussed in any numerical analysis text.

Comment: I am not sure about your answer. The point is to get the function $\phi$ not the root of the equation.

Comment: That is how I understand binary search in numerical analysis.  Maybe you know something about the form of $\phi$ and are finding some constants in it?  Can you provide more context?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve $f(y) = g(y)$ using binary search, then you need to find a zero of a function $f(y) - g(y)$.

For different values of y, you get a list of numbers:
$.., f(0) - g(0), .., f(1) - g(1), ..$
So use a same technique as finding a number 0 in that list.